# Increase size of an image formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field, image-formula

[image]

Hi all I have written a formula field Flagstatus which updates each time a choose a picklist value from the picklist field flag.The red flag is displayed when I choose red in the picklist and so on..
Formula field:

```
IMAGE(
CASE( Flags__c ,
"Green", "/img/samples/flag_green.gif",
"Yellow", "/img/samples/flag_yellow.gif",
"Red", "/img/samples/flag_red.gif",
"/s.gif"),
"status color")
```

My requirement is to somehow increase the size of the flag.When I searched I saw a method where I can provide the dimensions for the flag and I modified..
Modified formula:

```
IMAGE(
CASE( Flags__c ,
("Green", "/img/samples/flag_green.gif","green",30,30)
("Yellow", "/img/samples/flag_yellow.gif","red", 30, 30)
("Red", "/img/samples/flag_red.gif","yellow", 30, 30)
("/s.gif"),
"status color"))
```

BUt is not working.Syntax issue..

[image]

[image]

CASE(
Flags__c,

"Green",
IMAGE(
"/img/samples/flag_green.gif",
"green",
40,
40
),

"Yellow",
IMAGE(
"/img/samples/flag_yellow.gif",
"yellow",
40,
40
),

"Red",
IMAGE(
"img/samples/flag_red.gif",
"red",
40,
40
),
IMAGE("/s.gif", "status color")
)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indenting and formatting your formulas is extremely helpful in finding syntax mistakes or cross-checking with the expected format. In this case, you'll note that [CASE](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5) expects

`CASE(expression,value1, result1, value2, result2,..., else_result)`

and [IMAGE](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5) expects

`IMAGE(image_url, alternate_text, height, width)`

Likewise, what you're trying to accomplish with the above formula could be put in the following terms to match with the parameters above

- For a given *field* (`expression`), depending on its *data* (`value`) - return a format (`result`) to be used within `IMAGE`

If I format your existing formula and add a comment to match with the expected format above, you can see your parenthesis are bunching the value used in `CASE` together with the format you'd want to return for `IMAGE`.

```
IMAGE(
    CASE( 
        Flags__c,                                                /* expression */
        
        ("Green", "/img/samples/flag_green.gif","green",30,30)   /* value1 */
        /* Missing comma from above expression */
        
        /* Wrong alternate text for color */
        ("Yellow", "/img/samples/flag_yellow.gif","red", 30, 30) /* result1 */

...
```

You'll need to separate them out like so

```
IMAGE(
    CASE( 
        Flags__c ,                                         /* expression */
       
        "Green",                                           /* value 1 */
        ("/img/samples/flag_green.gif","green",30,30),     /* result 1 */

        "Yellow",                                          /* value 2 */
        ("/img/samples/flag_yellow.gif","yellow", 30, 30), /* result 2 */

        "Red",                                             /* value 3 */
        ("/img/samples/flag_red.gif","red", 30, 30),       /* result 3 */

        ("/s.gif", "status color")                         /* else result */
    )
)
```

*Note: you had mismatched labeling your image colors (red/yellow) as well*

Testing quickly the above, you'll still get errors. If you look closer at it, you'll see that the value being returned to IMAGE() from CASE is `("url", "alternatetext",30,30)`. However, that's treated as all one input/parameter (string) in `IMAGE` instead of 4 separate parameters.

You'd have to duplicate your CASE for each parameter to achieve it the way you were doing

```
IMAGE(
    CASE(
        Flags__c,

        "Green",
        "img/samples/flag_green.gif

        ..rest of case for just url
    ),

    CASE(
        Flags__c

        "Green",
        "green",

        ..rest of case for just alternate text

...and so on
```

As you can see, it's not very efficient. Instead, you can flip your CASE and IMAGE so you can return the IMAGE() with all its properties set

```
CASE(
    Flags__c,                               /* expression */

    "Green",                                /* value 1 */
        IMAGE(                              /* result 1 */
            "/img/samples/flag_green.gif",
            "green",
            30,
            30
        ),

    "Red",
        IMAGE(
            "img/samples/flag_red.gif",
            "red",
            30,
            30
        ),

    ...rest of your colors/images

)
```

Comment: Gonclaves Is this the way...........IMAGE(
    CASE(
        Flags__c,

        "Green",
        "img/samples/flag_green.gif
"green",
            30,
            30
        ),
CASE(
        Flags__c,

        "Red",
        "img/samples/flag_red.gif
"red",
            30,
            30
        ),
CASE(
        Flags__c,

        "Red",
        "img/samples/flag_yellow.gif
"yellow",
            30,
            30
        ),
)

Comment: Look at my last example - you'll want to nest the `IMAGE()` within `CASE()`. You should be able to follow the syntax to complete the rest

Comment: @Gonclaves Okay I believe I have updated your suggestions.I have added it and the end of my question as it is a bit long.Still a syntax error.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood what I was saying. Look at the final example in my answer (I'll updated it with more of it, but you should be able to follow the structure). You just need one `CASE` at the top and then return one `IMAGE` for each different scenario.

Comment: @Gonclaves I get it now.Thanks so much for the help.I did this way and I have uploaded the snip.I have closed all the conditions accordingly.Still it remains.Btw Thanks.....

Comment: Just gotta define that `else_result` (last parameter) for CASE - in other words, what's the image if there's no match on the colors you've defined? So `IMAGE("/s.gif", "status color")`

Comment: @Gonclaves once again thanks so much.It worked.The yellow and green flags are enlarged right now.But the red flag isn't enlarged.Uploaded the snip.

Comment: can you update your question with your formula you ended up with?

Comment: @Gonclaves Yes sir added the code

Comment: So it's not an issue with your formula - the image isn't pulling through. I would double check the path and compare that image you uploaded with the others that do work to see if there's any difference

Comment: Gonclaves Acutally sir I have figured it out..I copied the yellows condition and pasted and replaced with red exactly the same.Working right now..Thanks again..Hoped I could vote the answer but no reputation to cast votes.

Comment: Great! As the questioner, you can "accept" the answer as well (check mark under upvote/downvote)

Comment: Gonclaves Done!!!!!.Thanks